# Sublime Text 3 Python Interactive Console?

Tags: python, console, sublimetext3

I have been using a lot of sublime text 3 to write python. However, whenever a program I make needs user input, nothing happens. For example:

```
number = input("What is your favorite number?: ")
print(number)
```

This simply gives me the input prompt in the console, but anything that I type is ignored. The

```
print(number)
```

is never run. Is there a way to use an interactive console for sublime text 3? I have heard of something called REPL that will do the job in ST2, but I want to use an interactive console for python3 in ST3.

As of now, I just run programs that need input from terminal. Sometimes I'll use Pycharm, but I'm still getting used to pycharm.

Comment: I just posted [__an answer__](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36235655/4955183) that might be relevant to you.  It is a template for creating builds with input for Windows.

Comment: @Enteleform Sorry I use mac =/

Answer (score 2):

SublimeREPL works for python3. Their current builds are actually all tested against ST3.

https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL